# Detecting if Windows is version 8 or 8.1

Tags: winapi, windows-8.1

Is there any way we can detect  "Windows8 to Windows8.1 Upgrade" programatically?

I need one of my application to detect that user has done a OS upgrade?

Comment: what kind of application you're talking about? winapi? .net? web-application?

Comment: If it's Win8.1, you want to tell if it was an upgrade to 8 or a fresh install, right?

Answer (score 0):

You want the new [Windows Version Helper functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn424972.aspx).

Alternatively, use plain old [`GetVersionEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724451.aspx) and the information it puts in the [`OSVERSIONINFOEX`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724833.aspx) object.

Two minutes of Googling could have gotten you this.

Comment: `GetVersionEx` won't work on Win8.1